# Wrappanel inside ScrollViewer in two different libraries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, wrappanel

I'm new in wpf and mvvm, so i desided ask some help. And sorry, but english is not my native language. 
I have main application for displaying some documents. Each document is an external dll + xml-file with data.

In main application i have XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   Background="DarkGray">
  <Border Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" Padding="20">
    <ContentControl x:Name="ccCurrentView" cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=CurrentView}"/>                 
  </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In ContentControl i display view of my document as UserControl from dll. And we use MVVM, so XAML of document is something like that:

```
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <UserControl_Type1 />
    <UserControl_Type2 />...
  </StackPanel>
  <UserControl_Type3 />
</UserControl>
```

Any of these UserControl_TypeXXX can be inside its own dll.

Now users ask me replace StackPanel with WrapPanel for some type of UserControl. And, when user resize main application, some controls first wrap theirs elements and only then show scrollbars for all document.
But according to the information i've read WrapPanel doesn't wraps inside ScrollViewer.

How can i achieve this behavior if i don't have widht and height from main application and can't predict which UserControl inside my document should wrap theirs elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article about xaml anti-patterns](http://www.codemag.com/article/1509091) and it helps me a lot.  
In my case I switch between two content template. One with ScrollViewer for old documents, another - without.  
In Resources:

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="ResizableContent" >
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="DarkGray">
                <Border Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" Padding="20">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ccCurrentView" cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=CurrentView}"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NotResizableContent" >
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="DarkGray">
                <Border Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" Padding="20">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ccCurrentView" cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=CurrentView}"/>
                </Border>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
```

In MainPanel:

```
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NotResizableContent}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsResizable}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResizableContent}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style> 
    </ContentControl>
```